# Logo: improvement, what software to use, general guidelines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, software-recommendation, branding, sketching

I'm an amateur interested in graphic design.

What I'm doing is a logo for a brand called *Shelves*. I started sketching with the idea of the letter **S** + a book, shelf, sheet of paper or something associated with the name. That's what I've made:

[image]

---

Then I changed tactics and just started creating a simple **S** logo in Photoshop. I ended up with some weird stuff looking like they are made by 5 years old kid playing with PS. I'm talking about these:

[image]

---

**So my questions are:**

- Is there potential in any of my sketches to become a nice, clear, simple logo? And which one according to you would turn out a good one?
- What would you recommend as software for creating the logo? Right now I'm using only Photoshop and I'm not sure if I'm not using it right or there's a better software (*should I use Illustrator!?*) ?

I would be glad if you recommend me some tutorials, techniques, rules, articles or anything that's going to help me learn how to create a nice professional looking logos and designs on the whole. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you should be using illustrator.

Comment: Hi Johnson, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some certainly have potential. But it's not just a point and choose thing. Look for ones that have a **unique shape**, as this is the essence of every good logo. This unique shape should represent what you are trying to say, the **core values**, the **message**. And don't forget about what industry you are in, if it doesn't fit into the industry it will not easily be perceived as a service of that industry.

Technique/Tool: Illustrator or equivalent vector tool. But starting with pen and paper is fine.